# How to replace only the dbpassword in magento envfile using sed or any other method

Tags: bash, magento, sed

I want to replace the dbpassword in magento envfile using a script. I tried to use sed command and it replaces both password fields. Eg:

```
<?php
return [
   
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'dbname' => '',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
   
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '6379',
            'password' => '',
       
        ]
```

I tried the following sed command in my script and it replaces both db and reddis password.

```
sed -r '/password/ s/(^.*)(=>.*)/\1 => '"'"$pass"'"',/g' testfile1.txt
```

How can i replace password field in only **db array**. Sed usage with line numbers and instance count is not helpful in this case since that can be different in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use AWK here, something like the following `replace-password-in-db.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    replace_next_password = 0
}

/\s+'db' => \[/ {
    replace_next_password = 1
    print
    next
}

/\s+'password' =>/ && replace_next_password {
    gsub(/'',$/, "'" new_pass "',")
    print
    replace_next_password = 0
    next
}

1
```

Usage:

```
$ awk  -v new_pass="my-new-pass-is-here" -f ./replace-password-in-db.awk php
<?php
return [

],
'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
    'default' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'dbname' => '',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => 'my-new-pass-is-here',
        ]
    ]
    ]
],

'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => [
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'password' => '',

    ]
```